# Some review queues are accumulating because of daily review limit

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Some review queues, in this case **"Close Votes"** and **"Low Quality Posts"** pretty much stack up, because users aren't allowed to make more than 40 (or 20) edits per day.

"Close Votes" have almost **10k** open reviews. In my opinion, this is really not acceptable. There are reviewers who are willing to review more than 40 tasks who could also help resolving the long queue.

My suggestion is to raise the daily review quota. For instance to 100 instead of 40.

Comment: LOL. I look at the limit of 40 as "too much". Do I really have enough time to review 40 questions/answers a day. Maybe I'm doing it wrong by being too careful.